# Why can't Carto recognize the coordinates of my csv file?

Tags: carto, xy

Carto can't recognize the point geometry of some of my csv files. For example I can visualize in ArcGIS the point geometry of this csv file I have posted here. But when I upload the file to Carto it doesn't work it can only recognize the attribute data in the table but not the coordinates in the XY coloumns. I have another file where it works and the XY columns look identically which puzzles me. I have tried text and double as field type. And english and german comma as well ( "," and ".") All four versions don't work. What could be the reason?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you import a file into CARTO, CARTO checks if the file contains longitude and latitude column names like (longitude,lon,lng,longitudedecimal,longitud,long,decimallongitude,decimallong,point_longitude,latitude,lat,latitudedecimal,latitud,lati,decimallatitude,decimallat and point_latitude), if CARTO founds them it will use the values of those columns to geocode your data. If it doesn't, then it will search for IP address, city and country names to geocode your data.And if it does not find any of those values, it will leave the the_geom column with null values.

Due to your coordinate columns are called X,Y, CARTO does not use them to populate the the_geom column of the CARTO dataset.

I would recommend changing the name of those columns to longitude and latitude before importing the file to CARTO.

On the other hand, once the dataset is imported, you can georeference your data by latitude and longitude values with the [georeference analysis](https://carto.com/learn/guides/analysis/georeference).